# TS shorten code with repetition in if expression

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to shorten my code that currently looks like this:

```
                onClick={value => {
            
              if (value === "valA") {
                Mutation.mutate({filter, source: "sourceA" }, {someRepetitiveCode}}, 
              } else if (value === "valB") {
                Mutation.mutate({filter, source: "sourceB" }, {someRepetitiveCode}}, 
             else {
                Mutation.mutate({filter, source: undefined },{someRepetitiveCode}} 
                
            }
```

There is a lot of repetition in the code so I wanted to ask if there is a way to shorten that expression e.g. with a lambda expression.

Comment: Can you show the definition of mutate function?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with lambdas, just with expressions?

Comment: `value == "valA"? "sourceA" : undefined` cannot actually compile in Kotlin. The ternary operator as in Java is not present in Kotlin.

Comment: that doesn't look like valid kotlin syntax

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want but it looks to me that you want to assign something to `source` depending on the `value`. I think this is what you maybe are looking for:

```
source = when(value) {
    "valA" -> "sourceA"
    "valB" -> "sourceB"
    else -> "undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ternary operator in kotlin, you can't use `?:` known from other languages like `java` or `c++`. It is replaced with `if` which can be used as expression, or `when`, see example below:

```
fun some_func( lmbd: (String) -> Boolean ) {
    if (lmbd("text"))
        println("lmbd is true")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    some_func({param1 -> if (param1 == "text") true else false})
    some_func({param1 -> 
        when (param1) {
        "text1",
        "text" -> true;
        else -> false;}}
     )
}
```